# Selectable width of list items in ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity

In an Android project I am working on I have a ListActivity that is set up like this:

```
public class myClass extends ListActivity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      String[] menuItems = new String[] { "View", "Share", "Delete" };
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItems);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
      ...
   }
}
```

The 3 menu items show up fine, but only the text portion of the item can be "clicked". How can I make it so that the entire row is "clickable"?

Comment: By default the whole row should be clickable.  How are you listening for click events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of "clickable" area is determined by the layout of the list and of it's items.
By layout I mean those XML files in res/layout.

You have to set **android:layout_width="fill_parent"** for ListView and the items.

I see that you are using a **ListView**, if you are not loading a custom layout for the list, then **simple_list_item_1.xml** should be the problem.

Please post that file if the problem persists.